# Horner Polynomial Evaluation: counting addition operations

Tags: algorithms, induction

We first note how the polynomial in Exercise 5 can be written in the nested multiplication method:

```
8 + x(−10 + x(7 + x(−2 + x(3 + 12x)))).
```

Using this representation, the following pseudocode procedure (implementing Horner’s method) can be used to evaluate the given polynomial.

procedure PolynomialEvaluation2
    (n: nonnegative integer;
    r,a0,a1,a2,. . .,an: real)
begin
    value := an
    for j := n - 1 down to 0 do
        value := aj + r * value
end

a.  How many additions take place in the evaluation of the given polynomial? (Do not include the n − 1 additions needed to increment the loop variable i.) How many multiplications?
b.  Answer the questions in part (a) for the general polynomial a0 + a1x + a2x2 + a3x3 + · · · + an−1xn−1 + anxn, where a0, a1, a2, a3, . . . , an−1, an are real numbers and n is a positive integer.
What throws me off a little is the nested multiplication method. Those numbers have no value to my evaluation correct?

So if I began with j(n,x) = 0 + j(n-1,x)

So I solve this by (jnx + jn-1)x +jn-2)x + jn -3)x.......

Am I on the right track with this??? Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: each pass through the loop decrements $j$ and increments the number $k$ of additions. Therefore $j+k$ is a *loop invariant*. It starts with values $\ldots$ and ends with values $\,\ldots$ so $\,k=\ldots$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  It may be easier to do b) first.  Given your code, how many times does the loop execute?  In the line value := how many multiplies and additions are done each time it is executed?  Then for a), note that all the $x$'s get multiplied together.  How many are there?  You need to run the loop that many times.

Answer (score 0):

this pseudocode (may contain bugs!) may help to see the essentially recursive nature of this method:

function polynomial_eval (a:pointer; n:integer; x:real):real;

begin
 if n < 0 then polynomial_eval :=0; 
 
 else
  polynomial_eval:= real(a^) + x*polynomial_eval(a+bytelength(real),n-1,x);
end;

if the polynomial is $\sum_{j=0}^n a_{n-j} x^n$ then the array $a$ (with numerical address #a) is loaded with the real values of the $a_j$ beginning with the constant term $a_n$. however, this detail could be varied. for a polynomial of degree $n$ its value at $x$ is returned by the call

polynomial_eval (a,n,x)

Comment: ∑24_(=0)^(=4)▒〖_(〖−1+ 〗^(−1) )= _(〖1−1+ 〗^(1−1) )+_(〖2−1+ 〗^(2−1) )+_(〖3−1+ 〗^(3−1) )+_(〖4−1+ 〗^(4−1) )+ _(〖5−1+ 〗^(5−1) ) 〗

Comment: Not sure how to enter to show the correct format. Can you figure out what it supposed to be? And am i correct with this so far?

Comment: check out the 1-page mathjax guide: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference